# Javascript Getters & Setters in body?

Tags: javascript

As far as I understand, getters & setters in javascript can only be used inside objects, such as:

```
const myObj = {
  a: 7,
  get b() {
    return this.a + 1;
  },
  set c(x) {
    this.a = x / 2;
  }
};
```

Which means that you access the getters & setters only via the object:

```
console.log(myObj.a);
console.log(myObj.b);
myObj.c = 50;
console.log(myObj.a);
```

Is there any way to also define getters & setters for variables in the body of the javascript code? Such as:

```
function set myVar(value)
{
    _myVar = value;
    (some other instructions...)
}

function get myVar()
{
    (some other instructions...)
    return _myVar;
}

myVar = 123;
console.log(myVar);
```

Comment: you mean for globals? - you could `Object.defineProperties(globalThis, ....`)

Comment: ^^^ I meant `Object.defineProperty(globalThis, 'myVar', ...)`

Comment: Not *generally*. Moreover, this seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - why would you need these outside of objects?

Comment: In setter function we are modifying and displaying both values and But in Getter function we are only displaying values

Comment: @VLAZ I'd like to have global variables that, when updated, trigger other instructions. I can afford to have them inside an object if required, but otherwise I wouldn't have needed this object.

Comment: `foo = bar` triggering a function would be *very surprising, unorthodox behaviour.* For that reason alone you should avoid it.

Comment: @Denis So, it is XY. The main problem is implementing a notification system with updates. deceze is correct - using some magical "setter variable" for that is highly irregular. In addition, it's very problematic as it means that you have *related state* scattered around. Your expectation is doing a `foo = "hello"` is supposed to do some wider operation, yet the link between all this is flimsy and brittle. Implementing an observable pattern would be more standard way to handle that. There are other alternatives, depending on what's supposed to actually happen.

Comment: OK. Actually, I thought I could use that to handle values stored in the local storage. The syntax to use the variables would have been simple, while in the background, it would have used a more complex syntax to store and retrieve values from the local storage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). In browser javascript `window` is the global scope, adjust this to `self` (or `globalThis`) in other contexts:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'a', {
    get: ()=>12,
    set: (v)=>console.log(v)
})

console.log(a);
a=12;
```

`Object.defineProperty` is how getters and setters are made, the syntax you use is just syntactic sugar for it.

Since we use `globalThis` this will only work in global scopes. Variables created this way are not deleted at the end of a function.

Comment: This only works in global scope, not with any other scopes.

Comment: @VLAZ Correct, I don't think there is a "object" that can be used to represent the local scope